How to configure nginx so that I can download files via direct links to them?
I need to configure nginx so that I can download files that are directly on the same server in the /home/ folder and the URI is the path to the file.
Example links:
https://example.com/games/main/21/windows/ctulhu.zip  locate in /home/games/main/21/windows/ctulhu.zip
https://example.com/games/main/23/windows/OlympusoftheEternalVictory.zip locate in /home/games/main/23/windows/OlympusoftheEternalVictory.zip
https://example.com/games/main/questwindowsclient.zip - the same behaviour
How can I configure server part of nginx config in this case?
